# problem to configure pycharm into ubuntu 18.04

Tags: configuration, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I am new with python, so I installed python 3.6 and pycharm through the ubuntu 18.04 repository.

Even though when I create a project, it recognizes me that I have installed python 3.6, it gives me the following error

What I can do?
thanks for your kind help

[error to python configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9Ym.png)

Comment: Did you try to install `distutils`? I believe `sudo apt-get install python-distutils` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks @PavelKarateev